# WPF/Silverlight: How to disassemble a XAML from a DLL file?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I tried .NET reflector with no luck. Is that the primary way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out BAML Viewer plug-in for .NET Reflector.

[The plug-in.](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BamlViewer)

[How to use it.](http://help.syncfusion.com/ug_72/chartwpf/ViewingXAMLResourcesUsingReflectorBAMLViewer.html)

Answer (score 2):

with .Net reflector you can do it...
open dll with reflector and navigate to resources of that dll.
all the .xamls are there.

Comment: +1. The xaml files from .NET Reflector you just have to save to disk and then you view them.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems finding the XAML view in Reflector 6.0.

1. Add plugin via View -> AddIns -> Select BamlViewer.dll
2. Restart Reflector 6.0 (not sure if this was required)
3. Open XAML pane with Tools -> BAML Viewer